# Deploying Strapi on Kubernetes (GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to deploy Strapi on GKE (Kubernetes), I have a docker-compose file, and I think I can use kcompose to create the deployment.

My questions is, has anyone used Mongodb Atlas + GKE or should I deploy Mongo on my own?

Comment: were you able to create a docker image of your strapi-app, how many mb were it, could you share your dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

The question is more opinion based. It all depends on your needs.

If your needs match one of below you should stay with MongoDB:

- Your app runs on-prem and contracts or privacy statements dont allow you to store data with a 3rd party.
- You need large storage but not much query power.
- There is other privacy/compliance issues.
- Your app does not have internet access (firewalls, isolated environments)
- You are running 3rd party applications that require a very old version of MongoDB

Here are some **MongoDB Altas** advantages:

- Easily deploy, modify, and elastically scale their database clusters with a few clicks or an API call
- Gain complete visibility into the performance the database and the underlying instances
- Focus more on development, with built-in operational and security best practices such as geographically distributed, auto-healing clusters, and always-on authentication and encryption.

The best way would be if you will check how work with MongoDB Atlas on GCP looks alike. You can check [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/mongodb-atlas-appengineflex-nodejs-app).